# align elements in columns based on screen width HTML

Tags: html, css, web

I'm not using any framework such as bootstrap, just MDL, and i want to know if there's a way to align server-generated rectangular elements in one or two columns depending on the screen size, like these images where the black rectangles are elements:

[On desktop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sbvga.png)

[On mobile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZGoJJ.png)

Comment: Yes, it is possible to do what you want. But if you need help share what you have tried (html, css and jquery) and explain where you are stuck. If it is your first time asking, I stringly recommend to take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: I said all i had to say. I use no particular framework, no bootstrap, no jquery or whatever, and the will to make those server-generated elements to align automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that with flex , is very easy to use :

http://the-echoplex.net/flexyboxes/

hope i can help

Answer (score 0):

You can define different styles for any screen size using [mediaqueries](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp) in css

```
@media (min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1199px) {
    .example{
        width:50%;
    }
}
```